# Make dist doesn't include makefile.in files from subdirectories

Tags: makefile, autotools, autoconf, automake

I have a Makefile.am file in my source folder and some makefile.in in some subdiretories. Everything works fine but I've noticed that when I do a make dist the tarball doesn't include the makefile.in in the subdirectories. Also because of this, make distcheck fails.

Comment: Are the subdirectories listed in `SUBDIRS` clauses?  More importantly, are the sub/Makefiles listed in configure.ac in AC_CONFIG_FILES?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the only way this can happen is if you fail to specify the subdirectory is a SUBDIRS clause of the appropriate higher level Makefile.am, although it seems strange that 'everything works fine' if that is the case.  Unless you are actually naming the `makefile.in` with a lower case `m`, in which case you would need to add that file to `EXTRA_DIST`, but the better solution would probably be to use the standard name with upper-case `M`.